# Are reported load averages accurate on AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load, uptime

When calling functions like `uptime` (bash) or `sys_getloadavg` (php) on EC2 instances, are the returned values correct for that specific instance, or are they for the entire bare-metal system that my instance resides on?

I've been searching around for an answer on Google, and I've found [older posts](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=67697) saying not to trust those values; that CloudWatch should be used instead.

However, I'm starting doubt that's the case; on a freshly spawned Ubuntu instance that has idled for 20 minutes, `uptime` is reporting:

```
07:22:23 up 20 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

For my use-case, I don't need features CloudWatch provides - the load averages are just fine. That said, are the reported values trustworthy?

Comment: Have you read : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html
Also What is Instance Type ?

Comment: I just looked it over, but I don't see how it's relevant to my question - I'm not looking for a place to publish my load averages, I just need to know if the system reported metrics are accurate. My use case will use any instance size within the `t2` class.

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure whether they are accurate or not, nor why you would rely on running commands on the OS. What are you trying to achieve with the results? If you're alerting/scaling, then why not use the tools they provide? aka CloudWatch.

Comment: @d1ll1nger You make it sound as if relying on OS level commands is a bad thing... My current use case is pretty simple here; I'm just trying to track periods of high CPU usage and report them in a dashboard style UI. I have no issues integrating with CloudWatch if required, and I'm probably going to for this project. At this point I'm asking for curiosity as another project I'm working on needs to be deployable on both EC2 and non-AWS platforms.

Comment: @PhillipElm - not at all. I wasn't the one implying that it could be unrealiable. I was implying it could be overkill when you have base metrics going to cloudwatch by default, for which you ca use monitoring/dashboard projects that will just plugin out of the box. For example, Grafana for the dashboard with Cloudwatch plugin to gather the metrics. You can then plugin other data sources for other cloud/on-premise providers.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah that makes sense. Thanks! I'll look that up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reported values are for *your* instance, not the entire host system your instance is running on.  Generally speaking, they are reliable indications of *your* workload.

Load average should definitely be accurate.

The forum post refers to a case that occurs particularly on some older instance types as well as the burstable t1 and t2 instances, where your CPU % may not line up between CloudWatch and what the instance sees, because even though you are not really "sharing" resources with neighbors, you're still not allowed to use all of the CPU capacity  because either your instance is running on hardware that is faster than the instance type you are paying for, or because you've run into credit-based throttling (on t1 or t2).